# Apache-Camel 2.10.0: service deployment error in Tomcat7

Tags: apache-camel

I can deploy and run my web service (designed using Apache-Camel 2.9.2) to Tomcat 7 with Java JDK7 without much issues. However, when I try to switch to Camel 2.10.0, I get error during deployment ====>:

```
Aug 11, 2012 5:20:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR  
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\webapps\FacadeService.war  
Aug 11, 2012 5:20:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal  
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FacadeService]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) 
...  
...  
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:87)
```

I wonder if anyone has seen the similar error? and any suggestions on the problem? Thanks

Comment: are spring framework jars included in your project ?

Comment: Yes. The artifact camel-spring (I believe) in pom.xml loads all dependencies of Spring jars such as spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE, etc into the project lib and they are deployed into the Tomcat webapps. Either Camel 2.9.2 or 2.10.0 will load the same set of spring jars with the same Spring 3.0.7.RELEASE version.

Comment: Well, I "lied" to berkay - apparently the artifact camel-spring of Camel 2.10.0 doesn't load spring-web. This is a change from Camel 2.9.2. I have to add the spring-web dependency to solve the error.

Comment: it's great that you solved your problem, good luck.